# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes

Tags: android

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class
>   Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in
>   /data/app/woolamania.in.woolamania-2/base.apk)
>               at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at woolamania.in.woolamania.Home.onCreate(Home.java:32)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)

The code of Home.java class is-

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

```
TextView points;
Button freeRoll,lottery;
DatabaseReference mdatabase;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mdatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
    Query query= mdatabase
            .orderByChild("email")
            .equalTo("aroravishal8991@gmail.com");

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override


        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"in first if and dsnap dont exist",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


             for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                if(singleSnapshot.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"already exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

             }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post your app-level `build.gradle` file?

Comment: seems like a version mismatch issue. check if you are using correct dependencies.

Comment: Does this issue only occur on production builds?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have written this in your dependency:

```
dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
  // for real-time database
  implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3
}
```